# how to set a BasicEditField to accept dotted decimal numbers

Tags: blackberry

I have added a BasicEditField to a GridFieldManager. When I test it, it allows input values like `11.11.11`. How can I make my BasicEditField accept only correct double numbers, like `101.1` or `123.123`.  That is, allow only one decimal point.

```
    gfm = new GridFieldManager(1, 2, 0);
    gfm.add(new LabelField(" Enter value  : "));
    bef = new BasicEditField(BasicEditField.NO_NEWLINE|BasicEditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC);
    bef.setFilter(TextFilter.get(NumericTextFilter.REAL_NUMERIC));
    bef.setFilter(TextFilter.get(TextFilter.REAL_NUMERIC));
    bef.setText("1");
    bef.setMaxSize(8);
    gfm.add(bef);
    add(gfm);
```

i had tried everything that i can. but the problem is yet in my app. can anyone give me a proper way to design a input field tha accepts decimal numbers?

Comment: actually i had given my own editfield for that. now it works almost ok. but still i am having a problem, which i had when i used the same BasicEditField. it is accepting values like "1.1.1.1". but i want to make my feild to accept correct floating values. like "1.1111" or 1000.1". simply only one "." char. How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got the solution for a forum(forgot to copy the link)..

here it is...

inside my class i put the variables...

```
private int maxIntDigits = -1; 
private int maxFractDigits = -1;
private String old;
```

i had added a BasicEditField, bef..

```
bef = new BasicEditField("","1");
bef.setMaxSize(8);
bef.setChangeListener(this);
add(bef);
```

And then in its fieldChanged().

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
if(field==bef)
        {
            String str = bef.getText();  
            if(str.equals("")) 
            { 
                old = ""; 
                //return; 
            }   
            if(str.indexOf('.') == str.lastIndexOf('.')) 
            { 
                if(str.indexOf('-') >= 0) 
                { 
                    bef.setText(old); 
                } 
                if(validateIntPart(str) && validateFractPart(str)) 
                { 
                    old = str; 
                    //return; 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    bef.setText(old); 
                }  
            } 
            else 
            { 
                bef.setText(old); 
                //return; 
            } 
}
```

}

and then two functions in it...

```
private boolean validateIntPart(String str) { 
        if(maxIntDigits == -1) { 
            return true;  //no limit has been set 
        } 
        int p = str.indexOf('.'); 
        if(p == -1) { 
            p = str.length(); 
        } 
        int digits = str.substring(0, p).length(); 
        if(digits > maxIntDigits) { 
            return false; 
        } else { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 

    private boolean validateFractPart(String str) { 
        if(maxFractDigits == -1) { 
            return true;  //no limit has been set 
        } 
        int p = str.indexOf('.'); 
        if(p == -1) { 
            return true; //if no '.' found then the fract part can't be too big 
        } 
        int digits = str.substring(p + 1, str.length()).length(); 
        if(digits > maxFractDigits) { 
            return false; 
        } else { 
            return true; 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add all the objects into the mainScreen with `add(field);`.
and then trying to get value of that fields.

now in your code put

```
String s = bef.getText();
Dialog.alert(s);
```

after

```
add(gfm);
```

and

To accept number like `1.1111`.
then add

```
BasicEditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC
```

in `BasicEditField`Constructor.

Now i think you got your solution.

Comment: i had added BasicEditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC. but still my edit field is accepting inputs like 1.1.1. how can i overcome this?